# Does Chinese have a gender-neutral term for "homemaker"?

Tags: translation, word-requests, gender

I've looked up homemaker, a generic and gender neutral term for house husband, house wife, or a person who stays at home and looks after the family and does house chores, in the Pleco dictionary, but couldn't find such a word. I wonder whether any such word exists in Chinese.

Comment: You can predict a proper way to say it as 家庭主人, from 家庭主夫 (househusband) and 家庭主婦 (housewife).

Comment: 家庭主妇 or 全职太太, but for husband, I don't remember a common word, usually people just replace 妇 or 太太 with 夫, 老公.

Answer (score 2):

持家者 = 主持家中事務的人

The homemaker = the person who does most of the housework in the family

*In my opinion, it doesn't matter it is the wife or the husband or anyone else-- who ever does most of the cleaning and cooking is the homemaker of the family-- If both husband and wife share the housework evenly, they are both 持家者*

持家有道 - (good at taking care of the household) is a praise for a good wife

The term 持家 literally means "maintain/ holding the household" which also mean all the responsibility within the household belong to that person including taking care the children.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about who takes care of the children in the family? How would you account for that? Please update your answer and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Joselin Jocklingson answer edited.

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between 持家有道 and 持家有房 which my Android Gboard keyboard lists and 持家有方 which my Pleco dictionary lists?

Answer (score 1):

By Oxford Advanced Learner's English-Chinese Dictionary 8th Edition

> a person who works at home and takes care of the house and family 料理家务者；操持家务者